# Multiple navigations and pages on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type='text/css'>
    span {
      text-decoration:underline;
      color:blue;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    // show the given page, hide the rest
    function show(elementID) {
        // try to find the requested page and alert if it's not found
        var ele = document.getElementById(elementID);
        if (!ele) {
            alert("no such element");
            return;
        }
        // get all pages, loop through them and hide them
        var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
        for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
            pages[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        // then show the requested page
        ele.style.display = 'block';
    }
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">
     <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <div>
                <p>
                <button>Link 1</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <div>
                <p>
                <button>Link 2</button>
                </p>
            </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div style="float: right; width: 75%;">
    <div>
       <p>
          Show page 
          <span onclick="show('Page1');">1</span>, 
          <span onclick="show('Page2');">2</span>, 
          <span onclick="show('Page3');">3</span>.
       </p>
      <div id="Page1" class="page" style="">
         Content of page 1
      </div>
      <div id="Page2" class="page" style="display:none">
         Content of page 2
      </div>
      <div id="Page3" class="page" style="display:none">
         Content of page 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is the code that I have so far.
Right now, when clicking on page 1, page 2, or page 3, the desire page will appear below. This code is set up on the right side of the page. `<div style="float: right; width: 75%;">`
On the left side of the page `<div style="float: left; width: 20%;">`, i have an accordion with a couple button links. My question is when clicking on button link 1 or button link 2 in the accordion, how can I switch the right page from a selection of different pages keeping the same function it has right now.

Thus, first i would click on button link 1 in the accordion to show desired page on the right side and if i would like to switch pages, then i would click on button link 2 in the accordion and show that desired page.
For visual, please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ochoa24/Y2wdA/1/)
If you saw the fiddle, then the links inside of the black box switch pages within the div, but I would like to add another function and switch the black boxes depending if the user presses button link 1 or button link 2

Any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you'd like button Link 1 to show Page 2, for example?

Comment: Can you make a JSfiddle?  That would be easier for us to visualize.

Comment: I created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ochoa24/Y2wdA/1/) for a visual. when clicking on link 1 or 2, i want the black box to switch depending on which link you press. Thus, if i had 5 links, then i would have 5 pages(the entire black box) to choose from @DanGoodspeed

Comment: The links inside of the black box switch pages within the div, but I would like to add another function and switch the black boxes depending if the user presses button link 1 or button link 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain that I understand the question correctly.

What I believe could be very useful for you, is to look into jQuery UI Tabs: 
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/
and link the tab click events to the accordion menu.

**Edit:**

JSFiddle, including the jQuery UI tabs. 
Provided the code on how you can activate the tabs on a click event from the accordion menu. 
http://jsfiddle.net/kimgysen/BcCnL/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Tabs 
    $('#body_div').tabs();
    $('#newsfeed').click(function(){
        $("#body_div").tabs("option", "active", 0);
    });
    $('#myprofile_edit').click(function(){
        $("#body_div").tabs("option", "active", 1);
    });
    $('#myprofile_view').click(function(){
        $("#body_div").tabs("option", "active", 2);
    });        
});
```

Comment: nice, this is what I am looking for, i can try adding the second layer of navigation i have in my fiddle and see if it works within the fiddle you provided @KimGysen

Comment: Also consider using the $('#somediv').load('http://#someurl#') (Ajax shorthand) for dynamically loading content into your div. You can use this as an alternative, instead of loading all the subpages directly into your main page.